# Python del on classes

Tags: python, class, del

Lets assume we have a class in python:

```
class A(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print "Del!"
```

`__del__` is called upon deleting/garbage collection of any `A` instance.

Is is possible to do the same for a class? I would like to have some method called when the class itself is garbage collected, which I assume is being done at the script exit.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

---

**Edit:** Just as I have expected, everyone is trying to drive me away from using this technique (I would probably make such a comment myself:)), though the question still stands: is it possible?

I want to the the following: I have a class with a static member that needs to be cleaned.

```
class A(object):
    class Meta(type):
        def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
            attrs['conn'] = sqlite3.connect( DB_FILE )
            return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)

    __metaclass__ = Meta
```

I would like `A.conn.close()` to be called, but just before the program closes - i.e. when I know that no more instances of `A` will be ever created. I know I can do this with `atexit`, but this just seems very ugly.

Comment: Using `__del__` is already suspicious. It can make objects un-GC-able (in the presence of cycle, the GC doesn't know in which order they must be called since there are propably some dependencies) and since it's non-deterministic, cleanup is better put into a  context manager. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: You can make a factory class that has a `__call__` method to create a new instance of desired class and `__del__` method that does what you want

Comment: And anyway, I can't think of anything useful that can be made with this.

Comment: Never rely on gerbage collection for a particular set of behavior.  The run time is at no obligation to ever collect anything, even at program termination.  if you need cleanup, use a context manager.

Comment: In garbage-collected environment, destructors are a bad thing. Avoid it. Or, rather, ask a question about the problem you're solving, not the small technicality. Probably this would bring real answers.

Comment: Thanks for all comments, I provided more info in my question.

Comment: @pajton - your extra info confirms that this is the wrong approach. @TokenMacGuy is absolutely correct in that the cleanup may never even happen.

Comment: I know it is not very elegant approach. What better do you propose?

Comment: @pajton - you could use one of several ORM libraries that do all of that stuff for you behind the scenes. SQLObject or SQLAlchemy spring to mind.

Comment: What I write is meant to be a simple ORM:-). Do you know how `SQLObject` or `SQLAlchemy` handles DB connections? (i.e. has them open all the time and when they are closed)

Comment: Couldn't you use `atexit` in `Meta::__new__` and hide its "ugliness"?

Comment: I could (as I mentioned in my question:)) and even I do now. But I am looking for cleaner solution if possible.

Comment: @pajton - ah, okay :) I would maybe look at the SQLObject source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that classes contain circular references back to themselves - so when they are deleted they are not easily collected - thus the `__del__` method odf the metaclass is not called.

I could trigger it being called using Pypy's Python implementation, but not using cpython - either 2.6 or 3.2. And even to trigger that, I had to manually invoke the garbage collector -
The Python environment at program exit is known to be full of inconsitencies, and the chances of the `__del__` method being called while enough internal information on the class would exist to allow a sae shut down would be very slim.

Here is my Pypy session where I did trigger the call to the class' `__del__`

```
 ~]$ pypy                                                                                       
Python 2.5.2 (78826, Nov 29 2010, 00:18:05)                                                                       
[PyPy 1.4.0] on linux2                                                                                            
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                            
And now for something completely different: ``sorry, I'll teach the cactus how                                    
to swim later''                                                                                                   
>>>> import gc
>>>> class Meta(type):         
....    def __del__(cls):                          
....       print ("Arghh!!")                                              
....                                                                      
>>>> class A(object):                                                                     
....   __metaclass__ = Meta                                                                                     
....                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>>>> del A                                                                                                        
>>>> gc.collect()                                                                                                 
Arghh!!                                                                                                           
0                                                                                                                 
>>>>
```

**2022** - as of Python 3.11 a06, the `__del__` method in the metaclass works in cPython, if one calls `gc.collect()` after deleting all references to the class, just like it happens with pypy on this example.

Comment: `And now for something completely different: "sorry, I'll teach the cactus how to swim later"` It made my day. Thank you.