# Python static variable deallocation

Tags: python, memory-management, static

When is the below python static classs variable garbage collected? 
I was expecting to see the message from the static variable foo destructor.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Foo init running"

    def __del__(self):
        print "Destructor Foo"

class Bar(object):
    foo = Foo()
    def __init__(self):
        print "Bar init running"

    def __del__(self):
        print "Destructor Bar"

bar_obj = Bar()
```

The output is (Python 2.7):

```
Foo init running
Bar init running
Destructor Bar
```

I was expecting:

```
Foo init running
Bar init running
Destructor Foo
Destructor Bar
```

Comment: Not a duplicate one to me. The other question is about `circular references`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628486/why-arent-destructors-guaranteed-to-be-called-on-interpreter-exit

Comment: And what is a "Python static variable"?  Does this concept exist?

Comment: It works in Python 3.4

Answer (score 3):

So we would expect the reference to the `foo` object to be deleted when the `Bar` *class* is deleted.  And that is generally what happens.  If you try

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Foo init running")

    def __del__(self):
        print("Destructor Foo")

class Bar(object):
    foo = Foo()
    def __init__(self):
        print("Bar init running")

    def __del__(self):
        print("Destructor Bar")


def f():
    bar_obj = Bar()

f()
del Bar
```

I get

```
Foo init running
Bar init running
Destructor Bar
Destructor Foo
```

and you can see both destructors called in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4.  However, in Python 2.7, `Bar` is not being properly destructed during program close down.  As the docs say:

> It is not guaranteed that **del**() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

Why is `Bar` not destructed during interpreter exit?

It seems likely that the class in Python 2.7 is not destructed because of circular references (see below).  In Python 3.4 (after PEP 442) objects with circular references are reliably destructed (even if they have `__del__` methods) and this may explain the change.

However, this does not completely explain the difference because although the class is in a reference cycle, the class itself does not have a destructor.

It seems that in Python 2 objects with circular references are not reliably destructed during interpreter exit, whereas they are in Python 3.4. I give some more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33103247/1295678).

**Edit (more detail about circular references):**

Classes contain cyclic references back to themselves, firstly via their dictionary:

```
MyClass.__dict__['__dict__'].__objclass__ == MyClass
```

and secondly via their MRO details:

```
MyClass in MyClass.__mro__
```

Comment: This does not explain why it's not deleted.

Comment: It is a feature of Python 2.7 but I don't fully understand the design rationale.

Comment: Hmm - more thought and I have come up with a plausible explanation

Comment: Can you explain where is the circular reference? Please elaborate a bit on your last paragraph. I don't fully understand it.

Comment: @A.P. Well I'm not sure - I got it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5609683/1295678).  But I'm looking into it.  Certainly all classes have a link to their Metaclass and some Metaclasses have links to classes but not sure if all do?

Comment: Bar instance (bar_obj) is destructed  (I see the __del__ execution). The Foo instance (foo) which is part of the Bar class as a static variable is not destructed (i don't see the __del__).

Comment: @A.P. Works for me on 2.7.10.  Are you deleting `bar_obj`? In my code it is deleted when the execution of `f` ends.  I'll paste the exact code into my answer and you can test...