# Self-deleting class in Python

Tags: python

**EDIT**: Disclaimer - I don't mean deletion in the sense that applies to languages that aren't memory-managed (e.g. `free` in C++). Deletion here is to be understood as the fact that the superclass doesn't have the subclass as one of its subclasses anymore after its been deleted.

In Python, you can delete a `class` (yes I **do** mean a class, not an instance) by doing the following:

```py
class Super:
    ...
    
class DeleteMe(Super):
    ...

print(Super.__subclasses__())
# [<class '__main__.DeleteMe'>]

del DeleteMe
import gc
gc.collect() # Force a collection

print(Super.__subclasses__())
# []
```

I am trying to emulate this behaviour but I want the `DeleteMe` class to be able to destroy itself. Here is what I've tried:

```py
class Super:
    ...
    
class DeleteMe(Super):
    def self_delete(self):
        print(self.__class__)
        # <class '__main__.DeleteMe'>, this looks right
        del self.__class__ # this fails
        import gc
        gc.collect()

print(Super.__subclasses__())
# [<class '__main__.DeleteMe'>]

DeleteMe().self_delete()
```

It fails with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rayan/Desktop/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    DeleteMe().self_delete()
  File "/Users/rayan/Desktop/test.py", line 4, in self_delete
    del self.__class__
TypeError: can't delete __class__ attribute
```

How can I achieve this self-destructing behaviour?

Note: not a duplicate of [How to remove classes from __subclasses__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428679/how-to-remove-classes-from-subclasses), that question covers the first case where the deletion happens outside of the class

Comment: "In Python, you can delete a class (yes I do mean a class, not an instance) by doing the following:" No. Python exposes *no way to directly delete any object*. Python is a memory-managed language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python del on classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607937/python-del-on-classes)

Comment: Dare I ask why you are going in this direction?

Comment: Fundamentally impossible.  If a method of the class is currently executing, there is necessarily a reference to the class in existence, and therefore the class must continue existing.  Keep in mind that `del` *doesn't delete things* - it's the reduction in reference count that might actually delete something.

Comment: Note, `gc.collect() # Force a collection` is pointless, `gc` is the auxiliary cyclic garbage collector that handles reference cycles. The main memory management strategy in CPython is reference counting

Comment: Fundamentally, if you are thinking in terms of "deleting" objects, you have the wrong mental model of Python, because again, Python exposes no way to do that directly. The code you've shown would only reliably cause garbage collection if the global reference to your class were the *only* reference.

Comment: @CoryKramer I have a stochastic visitor pattern for a language fuzzer that relies on the structure of the subclassing tree in Python to generate nodes of the target language by introducing probability distributions at each node of the subclassing tree. I need to remove a node in that tree because some opcodes cannot validly be included in the target language under certain conditions.

Comment: You should not be using subclassing for that. That sounds like you need a traditional tree data structure, i.e. a `class Tree` like you'd have learned about in a Data Structures 101 class. Abusing the class hierarchy to do something like that is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: A tree isn't the right approach either. Each possible OpCode being a class allows me to abstract common behaviour quite neatly (for example going from an intermediate representation to the assembly form of the language). We're talking about hundreds of different OpCodes here. Some of them can be grouped neatly (for example bitwise operators) as they all behave pretty much the same behaviour but these groups of opcodes have a lot of overlaps and exclusions so a tree data structure isn't a natural approach.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not here to argue about the semantics of the word deleting in Python vs. languages that aren't memory-managed. I felt like it was quite clear in my example that "deleted" here means that the superclass doesn't have the subclass as a subclass anymore but I'll edit the question to clarify

Comment: It's not an issue of "semantics". It is clear what you are trying to accomplish, and i explained to you why it isn't feasible. Because **python doesn't provide any way to directly delete objects**. You will not be able to remove all references to your class object while a method is running. And `del self.__class__ # this fails` is pointless anyway. Again, you are not fundamentally grappling with what we are telling you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes I now understand the issue thanks to the answer below but it really wasn't clear that this is what you were getting at with your earlier comments

Comment: So note, the *actual* equivalent here would be `del globals()[self.__class__.__name__]` interestingly, that doesn't work either, even though it removes the class from the global namespace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
del DestructMe
```

This is not deleting the class. This is deleting the name that happens to refer to the class. If there are no other references to the class (and that includes the name you just deleted, any module that's ever imported the class, any *instances* of the class, and any other places where the class might happen to be stored), then the garbage collector *might* delete the class when you `gc.collect()`.

Now an instance always knows its own class, via the `__class__` attribute. It makes little sense to delete `self.__class__`, because then what would we be left with? An instance with no class? What can we do with it? We can't call methods on it since those are defined on the class, and we can't do anything `object`-like on it since it's no longer an instance of `object` (a superclass of the class we just removed). So really we have a sort of silly looking dictionary that doesn't even do all of the `dict` things in Python. Hence, disallowed.

You *cannot* delete data in Python. That's the garbage collector's job. There is no Python equivalent of C's `free` or C++'s `delete`. `del` in Python deletes bindings or dictionary entries. It does not remove data; it removes pointers that happen to point to data.

Comment: " then the garbage collector might delete the class when you gc.collect()." so, important to note, `gc` only controls the *auxilliary* garbage collector. Classes are often invovled in reference cycles (to themselves!) but if a reference count reaches 0, the object is **immediately reclaimed** regardless of what `gc` is doing